# Switching camera to front face causes to failure taking a picture in camera2

Tags: android, camera

i am trying to change camera2 basic example so camera starts showing preview on FACING_FRONT, but in that case snapshot stops working.

Here is a link to the example:
https://github.com/pinguo-yuyidong/Camera2/blob/master/camera2/src/main/java/us/yydcdut/camera2

I am sure, that besides cameraId change i need a lot more additional changes, but i couldn't find what else.

Comment: I found the problem, when front camera is starting, result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE) stops working, the state remains 0.

Comment: But anyway, is there any suggestion, why doesn't this work for the front camera ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many front-facing cameras are fixed-focus, so autofocus (AF) state remains INACTIVE, and the AF trigger does nothing.

You need to check if the camera actually supports focusing, and if not, don't use the AF trigger or wait for AF state to change.

To check if the camera supports focusing, look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html#LENS_INFO_MINIMUM_FOCUS_DISTANCE